# NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type - xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsarray

Though the same question has been asked many a times and the answers were to --> Typecast the array to the required array of class type.

Though i did it typecasting I am still facing the same error with the crash.

Here is my code:

```
let data = Model.dictArrayFromModel(dict.objectForKey("category_plans")! as! [Model])


public class func dictArrayFromModel(planCategories: [Model]) -> NSArray {

        let jsonArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        for categoryPlans in planCategories {
            jsonArray.addObject(categoryPlans.dictionaryRepresentation())
        }
        for plans in planCategories {
         jsonArray.addObject(plans.dictionaryRepresentation())
         }
        return jsonArray
    }
```

When i try to use for-in Loop it crashes with the error `fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type`

Inspite of doing the type casting the code is crashing. I do not know what i am missing. Any immediate help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S : 
The major use case here is I am trying to pass this `data` the Array or Model to class Model for further processing.

Comment: Can you show the output of simply `print(dict.objectForKey("category_plans")!)`

Comment: it prints the proper array that is expected. when i checked `dict.objectForKey("category_plans")?.isKindOfClass(NSArray)` it printed `true` too.

Comment: I have told your to just print `print(dict.objectForKey("category_plans")!)` not some bool condition like `dict.objectForKey("category_plans")?.isKindOfClass(NSArray)`.

Comment: I told u when i print it gives me the expected array as output.

Comment: What you are printing is `print(data)`, there is no need to initialize for printing, you need to simply add this line of code `print(dict.objectForKey("category_plans")!)`

Comment: I have edited my question with adding the usecase. Please take a look at it and let me know if you can help me with it.

Comment: This is the last time i'm saying, If you want help then you need to simply show us the output of `print(dict.objectForKey("category_plans")!)` there is no need to initialize anything for that simply add print line in your code and add the console output here in your question.

Comment: Figured out the answer. Thank you @NiravD

Comment: I think you now got it that `dict.objectForKey("category_plans")!` return array of Dictionary or something else not the array of Model. Glad you solved it.